# Handle error simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, class, error-handling

I am trying to figure out, how to handle errors if the #id or .class that is specified is not found using simple_html_dom. I kept getting an error that says "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 11."

```
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html($url);
$ret =  $html->find('#myId');

foreach($ret as $elements) {
    foreach($elements->find('iframe') as $link) {
        return  $link->src;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you know the exception name, a simple try/catch block around should do it no?

Comment: Well you should check the results of your operations to make sure you have populated objects before trying to work with them.  The bigger question is why are you expecting more than one element with the same ID (which should be unique).

Comment: What code is on line 11 that is returning the error?

Comment: @MikeBrant simple-html-dom returns an array for any successful `find` operation, even though IDs should be unique.

Comment: It could be a case of: return ( isset( $link->src ) ) ? $link->src : null;

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for iframes under `#myId`, you can use the combined query

```
$html->find('#myId iframe')
```

If you only want to find iframes where the `src` attribute is set, you can further refine your query thus:

```
$html->find('#myId iframe[src]')
```

`$html->find(...)` returns an array, so check whether the array returned is empty or not:

```
$iframes = $html->find('#myId iframe[src]');

if (empty($iframes)) {
    echo "No iframes found!\n";
} else {
    echo "Found some iframes with a src attribute!\n";
    // do your stuff here
}
```

If you want to look at all iframes, not just those with a `src` attribute, you can use the following code:

```
$iframes = $html->find('#myId iframe');

if (empty($iframes)) {
    echo "No iframes found!\n";
} else {
    echo "Found some iframes!\n";
    foreach($iframes as $i) {
        // check whether there is a src attribute or not
        if (isset($i->src)) {
            echo "iframe src is " . $i->src . "\n";
        } else {
            echo "iframe has no src attribute.\n";
        }
    }
}
```